# How to ignore files in deployment in Aptana?

Tags: deployment, aptana

I would like to know if it's possible to ignore specific files in remote deployment in Aptana? I know there is an option to cloak file types, but I only want to ignore several specific files (mainly configuration).

Thanks,
pk

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty easy to do this. Simply right click on the the files/folders you want to ignore and select Deploy->Cloak this file type. 
You may need to alter the filters in the App Explorer view to see the files you want to ignore. These settings can be found under the 'Customize this View' menu in the App Explorer view.

Answer (score 6):

In Aptana Studio 3.2, you need to go to Preferences, Publishing, and add the file name manually there under "Add file extensions **or names** to be ignored from all file transferring operations".

Comment: Thank you @saluce, I'm new to this and didn't think it through.