# Aptana: Exclude files when deploying a project to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, aptana3

I'm using Aptana3 to deploy my python project to AppEngine. There are some huge design files that I want to keep inside the project but don't want to deploy to app-engine.
Is there any configuration in Aptana that I can set and it automatically excludes my design files when deploying to App-engine?

Comment: You can cloak files by type and they won't sync: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842237/how-to-ignore-files-in-deployment-in-aptana

Comment: I don't have deploy option in right click menu, probably cuz it's an appengine project. Interestingly, when I want to go to publish on the menu, publish gets grayed out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure it in app.yaml. Look [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

To skip files add (in app.yaml) regular expression paths to skip:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.temp$
- ^example\.file$
```

There are a bunch of things skipped by default (e.g. `.pyc` files).